# What happens when back button is pressed in navigationBar

Tags: iphone

I wonder what is the function is called when the back button is pressed on the navigationBar.

I want to add some functionality when the button is pressed, who knows it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nicely explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920379/uinavigationcontroller-intercepting-popviewcontrolleranimated

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you want is in the `UINavigationBarDelegate` protocol. Implement the `-navigationBar:shouldPopItem:` method and set your class as the `delegate` of the navigation bar in question.

Comment: This will only work if the navigation bar is not part of a navigation controller. (If it is, you get "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot manually set the delegate on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to native controls, there's no way to do quite what you want, just using the built-in stuff. What you want to do is create a 'fake' back button, and stick it up in the left side of the navigation bar. Then you can set *its* target and action to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're talking about the back button that automatically is added to a UINavigationBar when you push a new viewcontroller on a navigationcontroller.

The default action for the back button is to pop the current viewcontroller from the navigation stack and return to the previous viewcontroller.
If you want to define a custom behaviour to the backbutton you'll have to create a new button and tie a selector to it's action property:

```
//Create a new barbutton with an action 
UIBarButtonItem *barbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doSomething)];

// and put the button in the nav bar
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbutton;

[barbutton release];
```

Edit:
//An example on how the doSomething method could be implemented.

```
-(void) doSomething
{
//Do your custom behaviour here..

//Go back to the previous viewcontroller
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: -1: This replaces the back button with something non-back-ish in behavior and appearance.

Comment: This is not styled like a back button.

Comment: I don't have xcode at my disposal for the moment, but this should do it.

Comment: No, this looks rectangular. Apple doesn't make the back bar style available.

Comment: If you want to keep the arrow shaped form of the button, see here: http://www.hanspinckaers.com/custom-action-on-back-button-uinavigationcontroller