# Custom behavior when "back" button in nav bar pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I know that you can add a custom "back" button to a UINavigationBar, but doing so removes the existing button with the tapered left side, as described in [What happens when back button is pressed in navigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980559/what-happens-when-back-button-is-pressed-in-navigationbar)

Is there any way to keep the existing behavior and look of the back button, but also be informed when it is pressed?

Basically, I want my app to play a sound whenever any button is touched. I can do it with UITabBarController via its delegate, but the delegate for UINavgationBarController has no such functionality.

Comment: My guess, will that view controller's viewWillDisappear: or viewDidDisappear: work?

Comment: You could a transparent button on top of the back button and catch the press then send it on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are the possibilities for a View Controller to disappear.

1. Clicking on a button (other than **backBarButtonItem**).
2. Clicking on the **backBarButtonItem**

Either case `viewWillDisappear:` method will be called. Keep a **boolean flag**. Lets name it **isAnyButtonClicked**. And set `isAnyButtonClicked = YES` whenever any button is clicked. And override the `viewWillDisappear:` method, and play the sound if no button is clicked(ie., `isAnyButtonClicked == NO`). Probably your `viewWillDisappear:` would look like,

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (!isAnyButtonClicked) {

        // Play sound
        isAnyButtonClicked = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This mostly worked. I got the last mile by adding some extra calls to make a click noise and putting a timer in so that it can't generate another click noise until at least 200ms after the last one.